# ssh key passwordless using bash

Tags: ssh

I would like to use ssh key authentication. I have a file that contains:

ip location

ip location

etc

i have a bash script as follow :

```
 declare -A mylist
 declare -A myarray

 i=1

while read line ; do

        mylist[$i]=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
        myarray[$i]=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')

((i++))

done <file.conf

for ip in "${mylist[@]}"; do
 for location in "${myarray[@]}" ; do

        ssh ${ip} tail -f ${location} > /home/log_${ip} 2>/dev/null &


 done

done
```

When i do this it asks me for password all the time.I have no idea how to generate a key can you please show me the steps.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-keygen

Answer (score 5):

Execute the following command from your host machine as the usual user. This will generate a public-private key for this user on that host.

```
ssh-keygen
```

The keys will by default be created under ~/.ssh and usually named as id_rsa (private key) id_rsa.pub (public key)
Now the public key can be copied to any number of remote computers and all further secure log-ins to those hosts will not prompt for the password.

```
ssh-copy-id user@machine
```

Comment: i have a small question. how can i refresh the ips already saved?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by refresh. If the target hosts IP has changed then you can just delete the entry from ~/.ssh/known_hosts and repeat only the second step above

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open an ssh session using your keys without having to putt the password I think that this is what you are looking for:
http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a password and security is not important, another solution is to use `sshpass`.

This is generally not a good idea, specially in secure environments, but in some situations it can help.

```
sshpass -p raspberry ssh pi@192.168.0.145
```

this can be combined with

```
ssh -q -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no pi@192.168.0.145
```

to avoid confirmation questions that prevent automated scripting from happening.

Again, only use this in development systems where different machines share an IP and security is not important.

https://ownyourbits.com/2017/02/22/easy-passwordless-ssh-with-sshh/